# Adding columns to table changes the sql of a view

Tags: sql, view

I have a very unexpected affect on at view with named fields when adding columns to a table which the view depends upon.

SQL:

```
SELECT     dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomFieldDepartmentID, dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_StoreID, 
                      dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_ShopOwner, dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_CVRnumber, 
                      dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_OpenMonToWed, dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_OpenMonToThu, 
                      dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_OpenMonToFri, dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomField_OpenMonToTue,
--..
--a bunch of other fields
--..

                  dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserAddress, dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserAddress2, dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserZip, dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserCity, 
                  dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserCountry, dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserWeb
FROM         dbo.AccessUser INNER JOIN
                      dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment ON dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserID = dbo.AccessCustomFieldDepartment.AccessCustomFieldDepartmentID
```

When other peoples code does a dynamic add column to the table AccessUser, the server or something changes the sql of the view!

EG:

```
dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserCountry, dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserWeb
```

gets changed to

```
dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserCountry AS AccessUserCity, 
dbo.AccessUser.AccessUserWeb AS AccessUserCountry
```

This greatly F*****s up my resulting presentation of the data....Its like the View tries to maintain the position of the respective columns.

Deleting the column magically changes the sql back to original.

So question is:

- What is going on? Is it the server? Some functionality in the CMS
  software (where the add field function is)
- Can I make a setting on the view to make it regard the sql statement 100% static?

Regards,

Steen

Comment: What DBMS? Accesss? With or without Linked Tables? Generally the solution is to recombile the view, which ought to be happening automatically but may not. sp_recompile on SQL Server. Also avoid adding columns at the end of a table, adding them in the middle is asking for trouble, and never use * in a view.

Comment: A [DDL trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx), perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for comments. @Ben:  MS-SQL-server 2008R2.  I just created at basic view to get data from existing tables in a CMS. Have no control over the column adding. Have stated all columnnames specificly, so thats why I was so suprised to see the chages. Still like to find out how to avoid, but do have the option to run it not using views...

Comment: Ha, I said "avoid adding columns at the end" - I meant "avoid adding columns except at the end"...  I have a job which I can run to recompile all procs, UDFs and views... IIRC, this was because I encountered that exact problem!

Comment: @ben, yes - thats what i understood as well. But unfortunatly the functionality that does just that resides within the underlying cms...well, not the first time i redone something on that account. How would i go about making a job to recompile a specific view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recompile a view or procedure execute the following:

```
/* View: */
exec sp_refreshview 'dbo.MyViewName'

/* Procedure, FN, IF, TF */
exec sp_recompile 'dbo.ProcedureName'
exec sp_recompile 'dbo.ScalarFunctionName'
exec sp_recompile 'dbo.InlineFunctionName'
exec sp_recompile 'dbo.TableFunctionName'
```

You can get the list of objects from sysobjects. It should be relatively easy to select these into a table variable, and generate a loop which recompiles each one in turn.

```
set nocount on
declare @o table(
    id int primary key,
    object_full_name nvarchar(1000),
    xtype nvarchar(20)
)
insert @o
select
    id, object_schema_name(id) + '.' + object_name(id) as object_full_name, xtype
from sysobjects so 
where 
    xtype in ('V', 'P', 'FN', 'TF', 'IF')


while exists (select 1 from @o)
begin
    declare @id int
    declare @object_full_name nvarchar(1000)
    declare @xtype nvarchar(20)
    set @id = null
    select top 1 @id = id, @object_full_name = object_full_name, @xtype = xtype from @o order by xtype, object_full_name, id
    delete @o where id = @id
    if @xtype = 'V'
    begin
        raiserror('Marking for recompile - %s: %s', 0, 1, @xtype, @object_full_name)
        exec dbo.sp_refreshview @object_full_name
    end
    else
    begin
        raiserror('Marking for recompile - %s: %s', 0, 1, @xtype, @object_full_name)
        exec dbo.sp_recompile @object_full_name
    end
end
```

You might also consider a DDL trigger to do this on demand.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this...... As the customer won't pay for the implementation, and the problem can be solved easily by not using views, I'll never get to test this though...but still....thanks!